# Is there a command link wizard to create a new MySQL username and a DB with the same name + password?

Tags: mysql

Is there a command link wizard to create a new MySQL username and a DB with the same name + password?

As for now, I always do so online from PHPmyadmin, but would like to automize this process from CLI.

The way I need should create a username + DB with the same name, in the same command.

Comment: Why don't you just use the mysql cli?

Answer (score 0):

Sort of. What you can do is create a text file with all the details in it. For example, lets call it `auto.sql`:

```
create database <name of db>;
grant all privileges on <name of db>.* 
    to '<user name>'@'localhost' identified by '<password>'
    with grant option;
use <name of db>;
create table `<table name>` 
    (<... column details ..>, <... index details, etc ...>);
create table `<another table>` 
    (<... column details ..>, <... index details, etc ...>);
```

Then, as the root user you can import `auto.sql`:

```
mysql -u root -p < auto.sql
```

This should create the DB, the user and create the tables for the DB as well.